# file_get_contents and curl not working via php but working on CLI

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl, debian

When i use file_get_contents with a url (http://example.com or other), it will return false with different context, user_agent, etc:

> file_get_contents(http://example.com):failed to open stream: operation
>   failed

However when we used file_get_contents() for a local file, it works. But it shows the above error when we try to access any file through http.

I tried the same using cURL and got the following error:

> cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host

According to some solutions on stackoverflow, we changed this setting in php.ini file:

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
```

I have also used snoopy library after including snoopy class.php

```
require "Snoopy/Snoopy.class.php";
$snoopy = new $Snoopy; 
fetchtext("http://example.com");
$text = $snoopy->results;
```

it is also giving an empty response.

If I cURL or wget the same URL using terminal, it works perfectly. But it doesn't work in the PHP code when the file is not local (through HTTP).

**Server details:**

Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Debian, there will be a group **aid_inet**. Apache should be a member of that group to allow to access network.

Run the following command to get the apache user. In my machine its **www-data**.

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

Try this command to add apache user in **aid_inet** group.

```
usermod -a -G aid_inet www-data
```

[Note: if you have different apache user then use your own]

Now, run your php code again to test. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion. It works well and due to it and with your support my issue is resolved now. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code, which could be the issue:

```
fetchtext("http://"google.com");
```

should be:

```
fetchtext("https://www.google.com");
```

(Google uses HTTPS, and always redirects to `www` subdomain).

Have you checked that the URL you're attempting to query is valid (i.e. structure, escaping of special characters)? It would really help if you can give a real URL you're trying to call.

Comment: That was meant to be an example. We tried several (non-https) domains. Still didn't work.

Comment: Can you give a real URL to test with?

Comment: That's probably the issue then. Is the URL you're trying to access accessible via other means (i.e. browser, command line curl, etc)? And is the server you are running the code on able to access your local network.

Comment: If you would read the entire question you'd find that we already tried accessing it through command line curl and wget. It works that way. But not in the php code.

Comment: Your statement doesn't make sense: `If I cURL or wget the same URL using terminal, it works perfectly. But it doesn't work in the PHP code when the file is not local (through HTTP).` Does that mean the curl / wget didn't use HTTP?

Comment: No that's not what it means. As mentioned above:
"when we used file_get_contents() for a local file, it works. But it shows the above error when we try to access any file through http."
So we did use curl / wget with an HTTP url and we did use file_get_contents() and php curl with the same url. But only command line worked, whereas php code only worked with local url(s) and not with an http url.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding from where you are running your php files ( apache or command line ), check that you have **allow_url_fopen = On** on both php.ini files :
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini